# Mobile data and Wi-Fi turning on automatically in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My phone turned on Mobile data and Wi-Fi automatically. Battery also drains very fast. I checked "Mobile network usage", and turned it off for some  apps, but suddenly, I started to receive messages  "Unfortunately,  Google apps have been stopped".

I don't know what happen. What should I do resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Thread](http://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-stop-galaxy-from-automatically-turning-on-and-connecting-to-wifi.688018/) problem was solved by below steps:

- Go to Menu
- Settings
- More Settings
- Mobile Networks
- Connection Optimizer and uncheck Sprint Connection Optimizer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Data and Wi-Fi automatically turned on at same time, even though I turned it off it turned on again. Then I tried "forgetting" all the Wi-Fi access points which had been scanned and saved by my phone before and then it stopped.

Comment: Could you reorganize your answer a bit to fit the OP's exact requirements? I'll help you out a bit.